# App having access to dynamic IP DMZ host in home network

Tags: ip, dynamic-ip, dmz

I have a set of Dahua home cameras connected to my home network. The router is one provided by my ISP. Now after creating on the router a DMZ host from the cameras' recorder I am able to get live preview on a smartphone using [gDMSS app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mm.android.direct.gdmssphoneLite&hl=en) just by scannig QR code of the recorder's SN.

Important note is I have a dynamic IP assigned by my ISP. I confirmed this sniffing network traffic between my smartphone and a router - the app connects to different IPs after some time.

My question is: how does the app "know" which IP to use if its dynamic? Does the ISP somehow annouce the next IP it should switch to? Does being a DMZ host have any importance here? I also checked on my PC that each old IP is not working anymore.

**Edit:**

If it matters, I noticed it communicates through P2P with Amazon hosted servers. Below is part of a header:

```
DHPOST /device/<serial number was here>/p2p-channel HTTP/1.1
CSeq: 95279184
Authorization: WSSE profile="UsernameToken"
X-WSSE: UsernameToken Username="P2PClient", PasswordDigest="<some encoded string was here>", Nonce="<nonce value was here>", Created="2017-05-15T02:19:56+02:00"
Content-Type: 
Content-Length: 178
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router from your ISP is likely a level 3 switch (router and switch in one device). Between switches and routers, the MAC addresses from each device are shared. Switches make a MAC address table consisting of MAC addresses and physical interfaces/physical ports that they're connected to. Routers make a routing table consisting of MAC addresses, interfaces (physical and wireless), and IP addresses associated with those devices. Every MAC address denotes either a machine or simply the network interface card.

When the router is broadcasting its IP address, other routers know to associate it with that particular MAC address because they now see that this IP address is coming from an already-known MAC address. Depending on permissions and security, MAC address information can be retrieved over a network for each device on that network. If you attempt to, for example, use Windows Powershell or Command Prompt and execute `getmac` for a certain host or IP on your domain or workgroup, you may get a positive result, or you may be denied that information.

tl;dr It appears that the application is making its own table and scanning packets for their originator's MAC and IP address.

Comment: Thank you. And how can I get "live update" (I mean automated query) of new IPs being assigned? I assume it is not in my local network of course.

Comment: Tracking your router's routing table in real time with a loaned router from your ISP would require third-party software.

Comment: How about a situation where I decide about the gear? What should I look for (function, not model)?

Comment: Traditionally, you would have a GUI or CLI to login to the router. The GUI would likely have an "Advanced" login with a password of the day. The CLI may have the same. Either way, it's a local login for executive mode to make changes. ISPs generally keep this locked away from customers.

Through either of these channels, you would be able to retrieve the routing table. The GUI would likely be explanatory and give you menus. The CLI would, if it were running Cisco IOS, accept the commands `show ip route`, `show ip interface brief`, and `show cdp neighbors` for connecting the information.

Comment: Many router operating systems like to mimic Cisco IOS, but they switch around a few of the commands. If you somehow manage to find out what operating system your router has AND you can break into it, please be careful. Once you're in executive mode, you're toying with the functionality of the router.

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. That is what I needed to know.

Comment: I would also like to add that your DMZ is only truly a DMZ with proper security. The ports of the router(s) on the inside of your DMZ should be closed. The ports on the outside/perimeter router(s) should be closed EXCEPT for the few that you want open for your DMZ machines to reach the internet (likely 53, 80, 443).

If the app is running on a segment of the network outside your DMZ, there is likely a port open that is allowing that is allowing it to view the routing information. Check your Firewall settings on your router. You can also try GRC.com -> Services -> Shields Up for open ports.

Comment: I am currently reading about DMZ security, also because my router provides only DMZ host, not a real isolated subnetwork. I will check your suggestions, thanks.